# How do I change backgroundImage url in JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, background-image

Hi I know that this is probably simple but I just cant get the url of the flag and the image to change. I'm pretty new to JavaScript but i've managed to get the three pieces of text working. Help please! :)

```
function changeinfo(person){
    document.getElementById("personname2").innerHTML = window[person][0];
    document.getElementById("country2").style.backgroundImage = "url('')", [1];
    document.getElementById("image2").style.backgroundImage = "url('')",[2];
    document.getElementById("ratingnum3").innerHTML = window[person][3];
    document.getElementById("ratingnum4").innerHTML = window[person][4];
}

var tango = ["Tango",
    'flags/uk.png', 
    "images/tango.jpg", 
    "2", 
    "3"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

```
document.getElementById("country2").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + window[person][1] + "')";
document.getElementById("image2").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + window[person][2] + "')";
```

Comment: It works! I owe my life to you, thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!